# Python - Updating Multiple Lines

Tags: python

I am trying to print multiple lines while updating them, for example:

```
Attempts1: 10
Attempts2: 10
```

I've tried this:

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess

while True:
  for number in range(100):
    print("Attempts1: {}".format(number))
    print("Attempts2: {}".format(number))
    sleep(0.1)
    subprocess.call("clear")
```

but the text keeps flashing and that's not what I want.

So then I tried this:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
  for number in range(100):
    print("Attempts1: {}".format(number), end='\r', flush=True)
    print("Attempts2: {}".format(number), end='\r', flush=True)
    sleep(0.1)
```

And get this:

```
Attempts1:1
Attempts2:1
Attempts1:2
Attempts2:2
```

And So On

Comment: The text keeps flashing because you clear the screen 10 times/sec.  If  you don't want it to flash, then use cursor control characters to overwrite the text instead of rewriting the entire screen.  See the cited duplicate for a starting point.

Comment: I've used the cited duplicate already and it works, but I am trying to do it with multiple lines, not just one.

Comment: You have to extend what the duplicate shows and use vertical cursor movement characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt works if you change the order

```
import os
while True:
    for number in range(100):
        os.system("clear")

        print("Attempts1: {}".format(number))
        print("Attempts2: {}".format(number))
        sleep(0.1)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it does work but since its updating every 100ms the screen flashes extremely fast.